# Moderator Election - Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

We last had a moderator appointed back in 2018, and we have had a moderator step down, so currently are running with just 2. Now, the good thing is that generally this site runs without too much moderator involvement - the community generally has things in hand.

That said, this is an opportunity to have an election. Who knows whether activity will ramp up in 9 months or so as a reaction to enforced time indoors...

To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Comment: **Big thanks** to the current and past moderators! I think that it is better to have 3 or more moderators per site, even for a relatively low-traffic one. People go on vacations, are busy with work, etc, and other moderators pick up the slack. I hope we have volunteers! For the past related questions, see also: https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/705/ , https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/581/

Comment: Not exactly an “me, here, <snapping fingers>”, maybe a tentative twitch of the hand? Not enough (yet?) for a real answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I'd run. I haven't been involved much because I just had another child and because there hasn't been a whole lot of activity. I've always had a passion for this community so any potential future elections pique my interest.