# Policy in regard to "gender" vs "sex"?

Tags: discussion, terminology

The comment on this question got me thinking about this wording: 
[How can I delete my contributions and account to Parenting.SE?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/how-can-i-delete-my-contributions-and-account-to-parenting-SE/64#64)

I suggest we should set a policy on which term to use and edit as needed to maintain it.

Comment: I've placed my answer to this as an answer instead of in the question... if someone wants to advocate the opposite answer they're welcome to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem here, since there is a clear distinction between "sex" and "gender" in English:

> "gender" refers to culture and should
>   be used when referring to men and
>   women as social groups, while "sex"
>   refers to biology and should be used
>   when biological distinctions are
>   emphasized.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15780/what-is-the-difference-between-gender-and-sex

Comment: did you see the outraged parent comment I linked to? clearly for some folks, there is a problem.

Comment: You have to realize that most non-native English speakers have a heavy bias concerning the word SEX. It's not their fault; let's blame *the media*. Also, I can imagine there's a certain fear of what the word implies in terms of what opposite-*gender* kids might do. Simply using the unambiguous word GENDER instead is such an easy workaround to these situations, I think there's rarely an argument against it.

Comment: @torbengb Even if that's the case, I think it's a bit odd that native English speakers should be required (on an English Q&A site) to modify their verbiage in a case like this. I've also seen instances where "sex" was actually *less* strong a word for ESL speakers because, not being their native language, it doesn't have the knee-jerk reaction of "sex omg!" that it may for a native-language speaker of English.

Comment: @Arlen: your "knee-jerk" comment is interesting because I see it the other way round; *sex* is more an act than a gender. I'm sure the simplest solution is that we all simply need to learn that it's okay to use *sex* and not edit every mention into *gender*.

Answer (score 1):

I think for the benefit of non-english-as-a-first-language folks we should settle on "gender". So for exampe:

"same sex" --> "same gender"
"opposite sex --> "opposite gender"

Comment: is there a typo in your answer? should it be opposite sex --> opposite gender? or am I missing something?

Comment: good catch David, fixed.